# How to run my service on a rooted Android 10 as a root?

Tags: root-access, gps, android-10, services, background-process

I have a rooted Android 10. And I've written a service which I want to run under too, in background. A service uses a microphone and location.

I've not found any information of how to run a service on a rooted device **under root.** I've found some about running some commands in a service under root, though, but it may be only a part of what I need.

How to do it?

*update #1*

- By "service" I mean "a class inherited from Service"
- I am not aware about the differencess **in my case** in regards to an init service, a framework service, or just a normal background process. However, I need it to run forever. I guess that it'd be an init service.
- It should be be restarted if it fails, or it it gets, for some reason, killed by the system.
- It's written in Kotlin. Which is to say, in Java
- As I've mentioned, I've rooted my device

Comment: What do you mean by "service"? An `init` service, a framework service, or just a normal background process? Do you want to keep it running forever? Should it be restarted if it fails? How have you written it? A shell script, a native binary, or Java code? How have you rooted the device?

Comment: You cannot run a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service) alone. It is an entry point of an Android app. So your question is how to run a whole app with root privileges?

Comment: @IrfanLatif why can't I run a Service alone? It can be launched via ADB at least.

Comment: There seems to be a gross misunderstanding. A `Service` is an [app component](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals#Components). And you cannot run a component without running the app. An app keeps running as long as long any of its components is running e.g. a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#ProcessLifecycle) or an [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#process-lifecycle). So you do not **start** a Service from ADB. You **ask** the Android framework to start a Service which belongs to an app. ...

Comment: ... And you cannot change the UID of the app (which means you cannot run it with root). UID is assigned by the Android OS at the time of app installation and it always runs with the same UID. If you need root privileges, run another process with UID 0 (using `su` usually, but depends on how you rooted the device) which performs the required privileged tasks, and you need to communicate with this process from your app to get the results (if any). I think you need to spend some time in understanding the basics of Android and Linux/UNIX.

Comment: `And you cannot run a component (Service) without running the app.` -- where did I say that I needed to do it otherwise? @IrfanLatif

Comment: `And you cannot change the UID of the app (which means you cannot run it with root).` - yes I can, by calling `setuid(0)` from NDK @IrfanLatif

Comment: *"yes I can, by calling `setuid(0)` from NDK"*. So you can switch an Android app's UID to 0 (root) by calling [`setuid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setuid.2.html)? Great. Please demonstrate that and have a 500-points bounty from me 

Comment: No you can't cash your reputation. But community will benefit from your knowledge and revolutionary idea. // By the way, if you can simply switch your app's UID to 0 (root) by calling `setuid`, why have you rooted your device? And why are you asking how to run a service as root? You already know it. But it looks like you are not clear what you are asking. Try rephrasing your question. Please note that development related questions are off-topic here.